# Определить MAC-адреса компьютеров, из указанного списка (задан ip адрес)

Tags: windows, cmd, vbscript

Помогите написать vbs-скрипт для определения MAC-адреса компьютеров, из указанного списка (задан ip адрес)

Знаю как это будет в bat, а вот с vbs все сложнее. Буду очень благодарен тому, кто может помочь.Но это вариант такой себе

```
arp -a >> file.txt
findstr "192.168.0.1" file.txt && findstr "224.0.0.22" file.txt
echo ' ' >file.txt
pause
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114911/vbscript-get-mac-address-only-of-specified-ip-address

Comment: thank you................:)